# Does Brave browser get supported in "browserslist" in package.json for a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chromium, package.json, brave

The code in question for my React app in my `package.json` is as such:

```json
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Is there a way to add Brave browser in the "development" section so it will support a React app?  I know Brave is based on Chromium so is it covered under the "last 1 chrome version"?  If not, how can I add it?

When I localhost on Brave the frontend does not behave as it should.  Many functions don't work and the page is far too zoomed out. I tested running the localhost on other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, safari, and even Opera, and everything looked as I expected (not like Brave).